# Finding a line break in a text string in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I was trying to find line breaks and carriage returns in a column in a SQL table and I am not sure about the syntax.

I tried:

```
SELECT foo FROM test
WHERE foo LIKE CHAR(10)
```

I didn't get any results even though I know that the table should return results.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 68):

```
SELECT foo FROM test WHERE foo LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'
```

**Edit:** to find all various types of line endings you should probably just check both:

```
SELECT foo FROM test WHERE foo LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'
                        OR foo LIKE '%' + CHAR(13) + '%'
```

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT foo FROM Table WHERE foo LIKE '%' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '%'
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
  SELECT foo FROM test WHERE foo LIKE '%'+ CHAR(10)+'%'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
SELECT foo FROM test WHERE foo LIKE CONCAT('%', CHAR(10), '%')
```